# Making R packages for installation by install.packages()

Tags: r

What is the difference between `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` files installed by `R CMD install` and `install.packages()`? I have made an example package with `R CMD build`, which I can currently install with `R CMD install mypackage.tar.gz` - and it works fine. I want to be able to install it through the `install.packages()` function (with a call like `install.packages("mypackage.tar.gz",repos=NULL)`). What additional steps do I need to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your OS. On Linux you can install your .tar.gz package with the command you specify. If you are on Mac OS X, you need to specify that you are installing from source package and not binary (see ?install.packages on a Mac). As Dirk said the .tgz packages are binary builds for Mac and you can build them on a Mac.

If you want to build the package for Windows see http://win-builder.r-project.org/, which is a web service for building binary packages from source.

If you are planning to submit your package to CRAN, but wan't to test is first see [Rforge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/)

Comment: Thank you! the `type` argument on install.packages was what I was looking for! (since I'm on a Mac)

Answer (score 2):

I think the `.tgz` is the *binary* package on OS X, just like windows gets a binary `.zip`.  Either one results from `R CMD build`.

So when you write  "have made an example package with `R CMD build`, which I can currently install with `R CMD install mypackage.tar.gz`" you are inconsistent as the `.tar.gz` was the *source* and the *result* of the `R CMD BUILD` step.   Start with the `.tar.gz` sources, make sure `R CMD check` and `R CMD INSTALL` work on them and then try `R CMD binary`.

Lastly, for `install.packages()` you need both the *binary* packages created by `R CMD build --binary` and a web-based repository containing file `PACKAGES` etc --- and as `help(install.packages)` says, see the `R Installation and Administration` manual for how to set up a repository.

Comment: You can install a package from source (.tar.gz) from a local directory specifying repos=NULL. So you actually don't need to have a binary and a web repo. I just tested that it works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks - the distinction was that my tar.gz file was source rather than binary, as you suggested, and my getOption("pkgType") was binary.